# TouchableHighlight onPress not working

Tags: react-native

I implemented a sign in page that worked up until I upgraded react-native.

The problem I'm having is that the onPress prop isn't being called:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
        underlayColor='#f1c40f'
        onPress={this.signIn}>
   <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Here is my signIn function:

```
signIn: function(){
console.log("SignInAction signIn")
this.fetchData();  },
```

The signIn button appears to be depressed when I click it but the log statement isn't firing.

Comment: This is not a problem with the Touchable button, you have faced with undined context to call function.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try calling it like this:

```
onPress={ () => this.signIn() }>
```

It looks like the "this" in your function is bound to the wrong scope.

Comment: I like this approach. Also of note, my code had this.signIn without the (). It works without the arrow function as well.

Comment: I had a similar problem: my onPress was called automatically inside a scroll list when the list was scrolled. Adding the arrow function fixed it!

Comment: you save my life. And it's brilliant to use the shorthand function to avoid the signIn having its own scope. Nice!

Answer (score 5):

you can also do it like this:

```
onPress={this.signIn.bind(this)}>
```

the rest of code don't need change.

Comment: It's better to bind outside the render function.

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you don't wanna use bind and since we're using ES6 syntax, you could write your function out assigned as a const and arrow-function (within your component) rather than a function eg:

```
signIn = () => {
  // code here
}
```

then you can still call it within the component like you already are without having to bind within the constructor or anywhere else:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
        underlayColor='#f1c40f'
        onPress={this.signIn}>
   <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This should keep context of "this" consistent since **signIn** will be bound to the component only once on initialization.

Comment: BTW all three methods are valid. Seems to be a matter of preference.